# Vertially aligning a DIV on the entire page

Tags: javascript, css, html, vertical-alignment

I have found a few techniques used for vertically aligning a DIV on the page, most of them outlined here:

http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/

But, the project I'm working on now heavily uses Javascript on a DIV aligned in the vertical center of a page. Does anyone know a method (preferably not Javascript based) to keep the DIV vertically aligned in the center of the screen even when it's height changes via Javascript?

And also with a `height: auto` property if possible, so it changes with my content.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want strictly CSS? This is quite easy to do with tables if you're willing to break the tables-aren't-for-layout rule.

Comment: Tables are an option I guess, and probably the best one. I'm not really anal about using tables for layout anyway, I think i'll go with them. Thanks.

Comment: http://giveupandusetables.com/  I'm usually a bit more patient than that, but at some point you just give up :)

Answer (score 3):

Give [this CSS-only solution](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html) a try.

Answer (score -1):

This is untested but try:

```
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
```

Comment: That's equivalent to `margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;`