# Dynamic DIVs vertical-align middle with CSS

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am looking for the best way of vertical-aligning in CSS. I experience that this is a not-well-solved issue: vertical-align property is not the same as in HTML. I need a code working like the *margin:auto* property in horizontal way. The code I am using right now is not working everywhere (ex: fadeIn the object). Here it is:

```
<div style="width:200px; height:100px; background:white; display:table">
    <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle">
        <img src="image.jpg" height="20" width="100" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the absolute position method used [here](http://haslayout.net/css-tuts/Vertical-Centering). It would be nice if you actually posted a jsfiddle with animations and whatnot so we can see.

Comment: Thanks, this link is very useful. I use the code in section "Dynamic Height Block-Level Element Inside Dynamic Height Container".
But: what if my object has to have a display:none property, because this fades in?

Comment: OK, I think there is no better way around the Internet, I accept this answer.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this tutorial on [Vertical Centering in CSS](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html). Related questions [Vertical aligning in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823448/vertical-aligning-in-css), [What's The Best Way of Centering a Div Vertically with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/whats-the-best-way-of-centering-a-div-vertically-with-css) and 
[Vertially aligning a DIV on the entire page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023829/vertially-aligning-a-div-on-the-entire-page) also contain some helpful answers.